# Has anyone successfully configured mutt for GMail on FreeBSD? If so, how?

Tags: gmail, freebsd, smtp, compile, mutt

I've tried following the instructions [here](http://crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/howto/howto_setup_mutt_with_gmail_imap) and [here](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2007/07/31/using-gmail-with-mutt-the-minimal-way/). Currently, I can read email from my GMail account, but not send—this is on a personal computer, so even if I configured Sendmail, I doubt any of the mail would survive the spam filter gauntlet. Both guides seem to require the `--enable-smtp` option for `mutt`, which I don't think is being exposed by ports. I've tried the `mutt` and `mutt-devel` ports and neither seem to give me that option.

On a far less important note, I also haven't been able to change folders, e.g., I get told that Sent Mail is not a valid folder when I attempt to go into it. If you can troubleshoot this problem, it's pure gravy. I really only care about sending.

Thanks,

Hank

UPDATE: For those who are interested, the `mutt` wiki has a [GMailOverIMAP](http://wiki.mutt.org/?UserStory/GMailOverIMAP) UserStory.

UPDATE 2: Although I finally solved my original problem (enabling SMTP support for `mutt` in FreeBSD), @grawity convinced me to use a relay and avoid `mutt`'s native SMTP support. With that in mind, I went with [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/). At that point, [The Quick-N-Dirty Guide to Using mutt with gmail](http://www.scottro.net/qnd/qnd-gmail.html) was very useful, including tips on how to enable OpenSSL for msmtp (so it can talk to GMail's SMTP servers, which use TLS).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't use the SMTP support in Mutt. *<subjective>* It's just [not the Unix way](http://wiki.mutt.org/?MailConcept). Much better is *</subjective>* to configure something like [`esmtp`](http://esmtp.sourceforge.net/) or [`msmtp`](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) or maybe [`nullmailer`](http://untroubled.org/nullmailer/) to relay email through Gmail's servers, and then let Mutt use the standard `/usr/bin/sendmail` way of sending messages.

Comment: +1 for good suggestions, and for the tricky full-stop-spanning subjective tag.

Comment: How likely is it that I'm going to get nailed as spam because I don't have a PTR record, my IP changes, etc.?

Comment: Hank: You're still sending through Gmail's servers (that's what "relay" means). You'll just let a separate program handle that, instead of trying to make mutt do everything. So to answer the question, it won't affect spam score at all.

Comment: Do you also recommend using an MRA?

Comment: Hank: Depends on whether you prefer all mail to be stored locally (`~/mail/`) or in Gmail's servers. Most MRAs do not support two-way synchronization, so using one would mean deleting mail from gmail.com after retrieval. **Exception:** `offlineimap` can work in both directions, and is useful because `mutt` doesn't cache IMAP messages. So **you choose** this time.

Answer (score 1):

If that config option is the issue (I don't know one way or the other), try building the `mail/mutt` port with:

```
$ make clean
$ make MUTT_CONFIGURE_ARGS=--enable-smtp
$ make install
```

Comment: I still get errors telling me the `smtp_url` etc. are invalid after following these steps. I found the `--enable-smtp` option in the comments to http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2007/07/31/using-gmail-with-mutt-the-minimal-way/ but I could just be barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 1):

The following sequence seems to work (hat-tip to [The Quick-N-Dirty Guide to Using mutt with gmail](http://www.scottro.net/qnd/qnd-gmail.html), where I learned the `-Doption` trick for ports).

1. `cd /usr/ports/mail/mutt-devel`
2. `make -DWITH_MUTT_SMTP install clean`